# Ques-take inputs and print the maxed stats of a student, but after taking 1 input, the other inputs dont register properly. Without char it does.Why?

Tags: c, string, loops, input, char

The problem I faced was input not registering properly. Please run it to see what I mean. The question was to take inputs from user and print the maxed stats of a student and to do it using strings and loops. I previously faced the same problem, without character the code runs without any issue. The first iteration takes all input correctly, the rest don't.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num[3];
    float cgpa[3];
    char name[3][50];
    int count=0,track=0;
    
    for(count=0; count<3; count++){
        printf("Enter student %d information:",count+1);
        gets(name[count]);
        scanf("%d",&num[count]);
        scanf("%f",&cgpa[count]);
        //gets(stdin);
    }
    
    for(count=0; count<3; count++){
        printf("The info of %d student is: %s %d %.2f",count+1,name[count], num[count], cgpa[count]);
    }
    
    int max=num[0],max2=0;
    
    for(count=0; count<3; count++){
        if(max<num[count]){
            max2=max;
            max=num[count];
            track=count;
        }
    }
    printf("The max infos are %s %d %.2f",name[track], num[track], cgpa[track]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more debugging info. Precise input, output, expected output. Elaborate on "Without char it does." Try for a [mre] and according to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `gets()` with `scanf()` is problematic.
Your student names will contain spaces that `scanf()` considers field separators, and `gets()` will swallow entire lines.

First, bundle your "student record" fields into a struct, and declare 3 of them.

```
struct {
    char name[50];
    int num;
    double cgpa;
} foo[ 3 ];
```

The following reads in a line at a time of "comma separated" fields.
Eg: "Donald Duck, 765, 3.54"
The fields are isolated with `strtok()`, each being assigned to a structure element.

The print loop shows things are working...

```
char buf[128];
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    gets( buf );
    int fldCnt = 0;
    for( char *cp = buf; fldCnt < 3 && (cp = strtok( cp, "," ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL ) {
             if( fldCnt == 0 ) strcpy( foo[i].name, cp );
        else if( fldCnt == 1 ) foo[i].num  = atoi( cp );
        else if( fldCnt == 2 ) foo[i].cgpa = atof( cp );
        fldCnt++;
    }
}

for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    printf( "%s %d %f\n", foo[ i ].name, foo[ i ].num, foo[ i ].cgpa );
```

You can take it from here...